# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'drawSquare' of undefined(Пишу змейку на js помогите пожалуйста)

Tags: javascript

Помогите с ошибкой Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'drawSquare' of undefined...

```js
const random = (max) => (Math.random() * (max + 1)) | 0;


let c = document.getElementById('c');
let ctx = c.getContext('2d');
let width = c.width;
let height = c.height;
let blockSize = 10;
let widthInBlocks = width / blockSize;
let heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;
let score = 0;
let drawBorder = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Gray';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, bBorderlockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
  ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
};
let drawScore = () => {
  ctx.font = '20px Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Black';
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
  ctx.fillText('Счет: ' + score, blockSize, blockSize);
};
let gameOver = () => {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  ctx.font = '60px Courier';
  ctx.fillStyle = 'Black';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
  ctx.fillText('Конец игры: ', width / 2, height / 2);
};
let circle = (x, y, radius, fillCircle) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  if (fillCircle) {
    ctx.fill();
  } else {
    ctx.stroke();
  }
};
let Block = (col, row) => {
  this.col = col;
  this.row = row;
};
Block.prototype.drawSquare = (color) => {
  let x = this.col * blockSize;
  let y = this.row * blockSize;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
};
Block.prototype.drawCircle = (color) => {
  let centerX = this.col * blockSize + blockSize / 2;
  let centerY = this.row * blockSIze + blockSize / 2;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  circle(centerX, centerY, blockSize / 2, true);
};
Block.prototype.equal = (otherBlock) => {
  return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
};
let Snake = () => {
  this.segments = [
    new Block(7, 5),
    new Block(6, 5),
    new Block(5, 5)
  ];
  this.direction = 'right';
  this.nextDirection = 'right';
};
Snake.prototype.draw = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.segments; i++) {
    this.segments[i].drawSquare('Blue');
  }
};
Snake.prototype.move = () => {
  let head = this.segments[0];
  let newHead;
  this.direction = this.nextDirection;
  switch (this.direction) {
    case 'right':
      newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
      break;
    case 'down':
      newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
      break;
    case 'left':
      newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
      break;
    case 'up':
      newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
      break;
  };
  if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
    gameOver();
    return;
  }
  this.segments.unshift(newHead);
  if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
    score++;
    apple.move();
  } else {
    this.segments.pop()
  }
};

Snake.prototype.checkCollision = (head) => {
  let leftCollusion = (head.col === 0);
  let topCollusion = (head.row === 0);
  let rightCollusion = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
  let bottomCollusion = (head.col === heightInBlocks - 1);
  let wallCollusion = leftCollusion || topCollusion || rightCollusion || bottomCollusion;
  let selfCollusion = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
    if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
      selfCollusion = true;
    }
  }
  return wallCollusion || selfCollusion;
};

Snake.prototype.setDirection = (newDirection) => {

  if (this.direction === 'up' && newDirection === 'down') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'right' && newDirection === 'left') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'down' && newDirection === 'up') {
    return;
  } else if (this.direction === 'left' && newDirection === 'right') {
    return;
  }
  this.nextDirection = newDirection;
};
let Apple = () => {
  this.position = new Block(10, 10);
};
Apple.prototype.draw = () => {
  this.position.drawCircle('LimeGreen');
};
Apple.prototype.move = () => {
  let randomCol = Math.floor(random(widthInBlocks)) + 1;
  let randomRow = Math.floor(random(heightInBlocks)) + 1;
  this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
};
let snake = new Snake;
let apple = new Apple;

let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  drawScore();
  snake.move();
  snake.draw();
  apple.draw();
  drawBorder();
}, 100);
let directions = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down'
};
document.getElementsByTagName('body').keydown((event) => {
  let newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
  if (newDirection !== undefined) {
    snake.setDirection(newDirection);
  }
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Не уверен, что в этом проблема, но `this.segments` точно нужно заменить на `this.segments.length`

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в чрезмерном увлечении стрелочными функциями.

Стрелочная функция не может быть использована в качестве конструктора.

Как следствие, у нее нет *специального* свойства prototype, которое присутствует у обычных функций. Именно поэтому и получается указанная ошибка.

Для исправления достаточно вместо стрелочных функций использовать обычные.

Либо перейти на использование классов, с использованием ключевого слова [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: благодарю,не знал

Comment: Помогите еще раз пожалуйста с уже новой ошибкой)

Comment: @Forxz, задай новый вопрос

Comment: готово,помоги мучаюсь уже дооолго))

Comment: посмотри вопрос про модуль fs

Comment: @Forxz, что за вопрос про модуль?

Comment: вот опубликовал,ты просто не отвечал ,и я удалил его потом.